# Exporting data from VIEWS in JSON

Tags: views

I am using the modules Views data export and Views data export - JSON support to display data from View in the JSON file.

I am currently using 2 different terms in 1 View for example: View name "viewabc" and Terms name: "term1", "term2"

I want my JSON to render data similar to this:

```
{ "term1": [ 
 {
  "color":"White", 
  "code":#fff
 }],
 "term2": [ 
 {
  "color":"Black", 
  "code":#000
 }] 
}
```

But I am getting my JSON like this:

```
[ {"no name":"<a href=\"\/color-management\/red\">Red<\/a>"} , {"no name":"<a href=\"\/color-management\/white\">white<\/a>"}]
```

Can you please help me to render my JSON similar to what I have described above?

Please see the screenshot of my view settings

[image]